# Uwp app how to make seek bar to seek media player element

Tags: uwp

I am trying to make a seek bar for my mediaplayerelement which has an audio source. I tried to set my slider's max value to the total second of the audio source but it sets the zero. But if I do the same thing after a little time, slider's maximum value becomes the total time of the audio
This is my code to set maximum value of the slider to duration of the audio file

```
if(file != null) 
{
     var MusicFile = MediaSource.CreateFromStorageFile(file);
     Mp3Player.Source = MusicFile;
     Mp3Player.MediaPlayer.Play();
     MusicSlider.MaximumMp3Player.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.TotalSeconds;
     PlayPauseIm.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Pause_Button.png"));
}
```

(Sorry for unaligment in the text I couldn't make it look right)
I think if I make an event which runs when MediaPlayerElement Started to playing, it will work true but I don't know how to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to set my slider's max value to the total second of the audio source but it sets the zero.

Actually, your approach is fine. However, the value of `PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.TotalSeconds` is not assigned Instantly. According to official document:

> The [natural duration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) of the media. The default value is a Duration structure that evaluates as Automatic, which is the value held if you query this property before [`MediaOpened`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_MediaElement_MediaOpened).

For you requirement, you could  get the value of `PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.TotalSeconds` after media opened  to make sure it is value held.

```
Mp3Player.MediaPlayer.MediaOpened += MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;

private async void MediaPlayer_MediaOpened(Windows.Media.Playback.MediaPlayer sender, object args)
{
    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
     {
         MusicSlider.Maximum = Mp3Player.MediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalDuration.TotalSeconds;
     });
}
```

The other way to get music duration is to read file's `MusicProperties` directly.

```
MusicProperties properties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
TimeSpan myTrackDuration = properties.Duration;
MusicSlider.Maximum = myTrackDuration.TotalSeconds;
```

Both are available, you can choose one of them according to your design.

Comment: Actually, I did the same thing and came to here to say I have solved my problem. But thanks anyway. I don't see any reason to use the first way which waits until the source loads, is there?

Comment: Yes, you are right, But it is indeed a time-consuming operation. And you could use `Task.Delay()` to verify the first way.